# Internet Explorer media queries taking effect when they should not

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I have the following css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px){
    .calendar_head{
        height: 120px;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
}
.calendar_head{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #6a7783;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

In Internet Explorer 11 (and probably other versions too), when the page is first loaded, the media query takes effect regardless of the viewport width. Only when the page is resized does it realize the media query should not be in effect.

Comment: Try adding `!important` to the max width media query css styles. i.e. `line-height: 60px !important;`

Comment: adding !important would make the media query not work even when the viewport IS less than 500px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the media-query after the normal class state.  Also, you can try giving the non-media query a height as well.

```
.calendar_head{
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #6a7783;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: auto;
}
@media all and (max-width: 500px){
    .calendar_head{
        height: 120px;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did first have the media query below the normal state and I tried giving the non-media query a height.

Comment: Never mind. The styles that were misbehaving WERE the ones I didn`t define in the normal state.